# Validate edittext in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have an EditTextPreference for the user to enter a Bluetooth MAC address in my preferences.xml file.  I am using android:digits to limit input to valid characters, but that will not prevent someone from adding too little or too many characters, double colons, etc.  If they do these things, the app crashes with an invalid MAC address exception.  Is there a way to do this programmatically?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Bluetooth Settings">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="prefMacAddress"
            android:title="MAC Address"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:summary="Enter MAC Address of the Module"
            android:dialogTitle="MAC Address"
            android:dialogMessage="Enter MAC Address of the Module"   
            android:defaultValue="20:13:07:26:24:32"
            android:digits="0123456789abcdef:"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions for input in your EditText. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

Comment: I got a comments can only be edited for 5 minutes error so ignore my first one.  I get the regular expressions, but I'm not sure how to do the preferences fragment?  Do I delete the addPreferencesFromResource and use an onCreateView() method?  Here is part of my existing code: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

Comment: @john8791 Yes. Just in case here's a link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html

Comment: All the examples still seem to show doing it in XML rather than programatically.  I ended up checking the validity of the MAC address in my Main Activity before connecting rather than in my Preference fragment like I wanted to do originally using the regex: "^([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})$" The regex tutotial was very helpful